# find and replace String between 2 Strings

Tags: sed, scripting

I have looked all over but can't find a sed or other command to do the following:

Search for whats between the tags and replace with a String.

```
<version.of.artifact>1.2.3</version.of.artifact>
```

Sounds easy enough but cannot find a command that does both.

I am able to find and print value with:

```
sed -n 's:.*<version.of.artifact>\(.*\)</version.of.artifact>.*:\1:p' myFile.txt
```

But I want to replace the value (1.2.3) with another value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Solved - and updated answer below use variables:

```
sed -i "s:\(<$var1>\)[^<]*\(</$var1>\):\1$var2\2:" pomtest.xml
```

Comment: So you know that you can capture some text with `\(...\)` and then refer to it later using `\1` but can't figure out how to capture `.*<version.of.artifact>` and refer to it later? Just THINK about what your existing script is doing with each segment of the input line - the answers are all right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat myFile.txt 
lkadfkjh<version.of.artifact>aaa</version.of.artifact>lksfdkjh

$ sed 's:\(<version\.of\.artifact>\)[^<]*\(</version\.of\.artifact>\):\1NewString\2:' myFile.txt
lkadfkjh<version.of.artifact>NewString</version.of.artifact>lksfdkjh
```

- Using `\(` and `\)` to copy the tags
- `[^<]*` matches everything before the start of the next closing tag
- `\1...\2` placing something new between the tags

Comment: I think you need to escape `.` to  avoid  problems with`<versionXofXartifact>aaa</versionXofXartifact>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to do it

```
$ cat f.awk
function init() {
    tag = "version.of.artifact"
    b   = "<"  tag ">"
    e   = "</" tag ">"

    lb  = length(b)
    le  = length(e)
}

function upd(old) {
    return "String"
}

function ss(s, a, b) { # substring of `s' from `a' to `b' excluding `b'
    return substr(s, a, b-a)
}

function repl(s,   ie, prefix, old, new, ans) {
    while (ib = index(s, b)) {
      ie  = index(s, e)
      if (!ie) {
          print "ERROR: cannot find a closing tag" | "cat 1>&2"; exit 1
      }
      prefix = ss(s, 1, ib) # befor the tag
      old = ss(s, ib + lb, ie) # old value of this tag
      new = upd(old)
      ans = ans prefix b new e
      s   = substr(s, ie + le) # after the tag
    }
    ans = ans s
    return ans
}

BEGIN {
    init()
}

{
    print repl($0)
}
```

Example:

```
$ cat file.dat
text1
ab<version.of.artifact>1.2.3</version.of.artifact>cd<version.of.artifact>{1.2.3}</version.of.artifact>ef
<version.of.artifact>1.2.3</version.of.artifact>
text2
```

Usage:

```
awk -f f.awk file.dat
```

Output:

```
text1
ab<version.of.artifact>String</version.of.artifact>cd<version.of.artifact>String</version.of.artifact>ef
<version.of.artifact>String</version.of.artifact>
text2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser to parse XML: for example with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
$ cat file.xml
<version.of.artifact>1.2.3</version.of.artifact>

$ xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update '//version.of.artifact' --value "4.5.6.7" file.xml

$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<version.of.artifact>4.5.6.7</version.of.artifact>
```